# JavaScript replace behaves differently in Chrome to IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

The following JavaScript works perfectly in Chrome to replace a string:

```
myUrl = someUrl.replace('%2C%7B%22itn%22%3A%5B%22%20guidelines%20%22%5D%7D', '');
```

but in Internet Explorer it fails to replace the string.

It seems that it is related to how IE treats `%22` as if I debug this code and replace `%22` with `"` it works in debug. If I try doing this in the script itself it then errors in both Chrome and IE.

How can I make this script work cross browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known bug](http://www.pcworld.com/article/248408/ie_uri_encoding_behavior_facilitates_xss_attacks_researchers_say.html) in Internet Explorer that it doesn't encode `"` in the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) part of a URL. Try replacing URLs both when `%22` and `"` are used.

For example, it is possible to do this using a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
myUrl = someUrl.replace(/%2C%7B%22itn(?:%22|")%3A%5B(?:%22|")%20guidelines%20(?:%22|")%5D%7D/, '');
```